# If else formula field condition

Tags: apex

In my object record type i have created formula field. Now i want my formula field to work as below.

If Basement__c = NA and Property__r.Basement__c = NA OR 
Basement__c = Crawl and Property__r.Basement__c = Crawl OR
 Basement__c = Slab and Property__r.Basement__c = Slab Then it will return Type__c(formula field) = "MAtch"

And (Another rule) Basement__c DOES NOT contain any of the following "N/A,Crawl,Slab,None and Property__r.Basement__c Does not contain any of this then formula field will return "HAs basement"

How can i achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Are these 2 different formula fields, or you can have it combined in one? Also, what N/A value do you have in your picklists - "N/A", "NA", or ""(blank)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First formula:

```
IF(
    CASE( Basement__c, "N/A",1, "Crawl",2, "Slab",3,4) =
    CASE( Property__r.Basement__c, "N/A",1, "Crawl",2, "Slab",3,5),
  "Match", 
  "No Match"
)
```

Optimizations used here:

Since you're asking the two fields to be the same, that reduces the complexity of the formula. Next, we use CASE to remove most of the field references.

---

Second Formula:

```
IF(
  NOT(
    OR(
    CASE( Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1,
    CASE( Property__r.Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1
    )
  ),
  "Has Basement",
  "Does not have basement"
)
```

Optimizations used here:

De Morgan's Law allows us to transform (NOT A AND NOT B) to simply "NOT (A OR B)". Again, we use CASE to reduce the number of field references used here.

Comment: And this is picklist field, So do i need to add like PICKLIST( REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c = 'NA'  ?

Comment: @Salesfor_dev No, CASE supports picklist values directly. Just make sure the values are correct (you used NA sometimes and N/A other times).

Comment: Ok thanks, And i want to use this both formula in one formula field. So is there any way i can apply this both formula on one field?

Comment: Sure, you can concatenate them together using *text concatenation operator* &: `IF(...) & IF(...)`.

Comment: Tried that but getting picklist error like,      Field Basement__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain function

Comment: @Salesfor_dev Sorry, I just realized that the first part was the problem. I've revised the formula. Try it out. (Edit: Just updated again, so do refresh).

Comment: This is working fine, Only problem is i want to use this both formula on one field, but only one formula which is true will display result, the one which is false should not display result. . How can i do like that?

Comment: You can just use an empty string for the false branches.

Comment: Do you know how can i do like Property__r.Basement__c = Null then it will return null, right now its returning some value anyhow.

Comment: @Salesfor_dev `IF(ISPICKVAL(Property__r.Basement__c,''), null, (rest of formula here))`

Answer (score 0):

this will get what you wanted:
`IF(
 AND(
  CONTAINS("N/A:Crawl:Slab",TEXT(Basement__c)),
  Basement__c = Property__r.Basement__c
 ),
"Match",
 IF(
  OR(
   CONTAINS("N/A:Crawl:Slab:None",TEXT(Basement__c)),
   CONTAINS("N/A:Crawl:Slab:None",TEXT(Property__r.Basement__c))
  )
 "",
 "Has Basement"
 )
)`