# Nested if formula in formula field

Tags: apex, formula

Below is my formula if condition, which is working fine. I just want to add formula like is property__c!= null, Only then below formula will run.

how can i do that?

Ex.
If property__c!= null

Only then

```
IF(
  NOT(
    OR(
    CASE( REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1,
    CASE( Top_Property__r.REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1

  )),
  True,
  false
)
```

Comment: What do you mean "Will Not run"? Is this a Validation Rule or a simple formula field?

Comment: This is simple formula field, I want if condition like If property__c!= null Then Rest of code which i posted. Make sense?

Comment: Not really. If this is a formula field, something has to happen... I am assuming you want the value "false" to happen and, based on that, I sent some code your way

Comment: Why are you asking different questions (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/118724/12440) for the same problem? Isn't it better to describe what you have to achieve and ask for help rather asking to fix your failed approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will only return true if the Property is not null AND the rest of the code matches. If not, it return false.

```
IF(
  AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Property__c)),
    NOT(
      OR(
       CASE( REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1,
       CASE( Top_Property__r.REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1

  ))),
  True,
  false
)
```

Comment: Tried this one, This returning true even if my porperty is null.

Comment: Try now. (I Changed "IsNull" for "IsBlank"). If the property is an empty string it could be blank instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the syntax of If logic

```
if(Condition,True,False)
```

So if you replace Condition with your property__c!=null it will work for you

```
if(property__c!=null,IF(
  NOT(
    OR(
    CASE( REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1,
    CASE( Top_Property__r.REOHQ__REOHQ_Basement__c, "N/A",1,  "Crawl",1, "Slab",1, "None",1, 0)=1

  )),
  True,
  false
),false);
```